# Can't subclass Tensorflow RNNCell for custom recurrent architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to subclass RNNCell for a custom recurrent model but I get the following error

```
File "python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 508, in dynamic_rnn
raise TypeError("cell must be an instance of RNNCell")
```

The subclass has the following structure

```
import tensorflow as tf

class CSCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
def __init__(self, mem_size=64, word_size=4, batch_size=16, hidden_size=16, output_size=4):
    super(CSCell, self).__init__()
@property
def output_size(self):
    return self._output_size
@property
def state_size(self):
    return self._total_state_vector_size

def zero_state(self, batch_size, dtype):
    #zero vectors here 
    return zero_tensor

#(output, new_state) = self.__call__(inputs,state)
def __call__(self, inputs, state):
#implementation
    return (output, new_state)
```

In another file I use it like the following:

```
cscell_tf_core = cscell_tf.CSCell(FLAGS.mem_size,
FLAGS.word_size,
FLAGS.batch_size,
FLAGS.hidden_size,
output_size=64)

output_sequence, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
cell=cscell_tf_core,
inputs=dataset_tensors.observations,
time_major=True)
```

My guess was that CSCell subclassing is not recognized by the dynamic_rnn but I am unable to understand the reason. I use Tensorflow version 1.2. I am stuck and any directions are much appreciated.

Comment: According to the code https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L508 is thrown if https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L54 returns False. It's not a real instance check but attribute and callability check. Double check for simple typos in method names. It should work if your class has attributes `output_size, state_size, zero_state` and is callable. Check indentation also as it's unclear - you pasted unindented code.